# How to obtain shared data in nextjs application? Writing getInitialProps in app.js defeats the purpose of using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to fetch translations from AWS S3 bucket and put them in the context so that my whole application can use it and not just one page. Where shall I fetch this translation data?
In app.js we can't use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`, and we are not suggested to use `getInitialProps` (I am getting confused to use it anyway as its documentation is not very clear), I saw below snippet on web, but I am not sure where would I get the prop I am looking for and where should I fetch the end-point in getInitialProps :

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import { appWithTranslation } from '../i18n'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
  // shall I fetch my data here and provide the prop as
  // const xx = fetch('url')?
  return { ...appProps, xx }
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp)
```

It opts out of automatic static generation when used in _app.js? what does it mean?
Will I not be able to use any client side code if I use getInitialProps in app.js?

Comment: Automatic static optimization means that Next.js will statically optimize your page automatically by pre-rendering the page to static HTML. When a page uses `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps` the page is rendered on-demand for each request, meaning Next.js cannot apply automatic static optimization in that case. You can certainly still use client-side code when using `getInitialProps`.